# Fisher's test with zeros

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I have two conditions: treatment and placebo; and I am performing multiple tests to see which of the tests are best to distinguish between the two conditions. For the same I'm using fisher's exact test since the number of subjects in two conditions are quite small. But for some of these tests the placebo takes zero value for both before and after conditions.
[image: example]

I don't want to exclude these tests from my analysis. Is there a way to incorporate them for my study?

Comment: Presumably, these are 0's out of some possible total (eg, 0 patients out of 10 have a heart attack). What are the denominators? Can you paste in the complete data?

Comment: Yes of course. The total number of participants in the treatment case is 17 and for the placebo case is 16.